# Unit test failing after migrating to Xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a suite of unit tests for my app that were running fine on Xcode 9.4.1. After upgrading to 10.1, I'm experiencing a failure around asserting that a weak reference var is nil after setting it's respective var it points at to nil. Any ideas why this will fail now that I've upgraded? Other tests follow this pattern, but aren't failing.
EDIT: here's the new, non-failing code. just needed to init the button in the performSetup() autoreleasepool{}...

```
var button: CustomButton!
var buttonSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)

override func performSetup(file: StaticString = #file, line: UInt = #line) {
    super.performSetup(file: file, line: line)


    autoreleasepool {
        if button == nil {
            button = CustomButton()
            buttonSize = button.designDataMinimumButtonSize()
        }
        addToAndCenterWithinHostView(subview: button)
    }
}

override func performTeardown(file: StaticString = #file, line: UInt = #line) {
    // Verify that no strong reference cycles keep the test objects alive.
    weak var weakComponent = button

    autoreleasepool {
        button.removeFromSuperview()
        button = nil

        super.performTeardown(file: file, line: line)
    }

    // This assertion tests for strong reference cycles in the tested code.
    // However, if the assertion fails, it may be because the test did not
    // wait for a closure that was asynchronously dispatched to finish. In
    // that case, there is not a bug in the tested code and the test should
    // be modified to wait for the dispatched closure to finish.
    XCTAssertNil(weakComponent, "Expected no strong references to 'button' to exist.")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by putting the initialization of the button in the performSetup() method's autoreleasepool{}. Answer edited with new code...

Comment: No, you edited the _question_. Show the old nonworking code in the question and the fixed code in the answer. Thanks!